# Random access of Vertices using Boost::graph

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I am trying to iterate over my boost graph's vertices in parallel using OpenMP. This seems to require having an iterator that supports random access of elements (e.g., `itr[i]` gets the `i`th element). However, the iterator that `vertices(g)` returns (a `vertex_iterator`) does not seem to support this. Is there an efficient, clean way to accomplish this? Ideally, I just want a standard for loop such as this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_vertices; i++) {
  vertex v = itr[i];
  // Compute on vertex
}
```

which will cooperate with OpenMP. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a `adjacency_list<..., vecS, ...>` or `adjacency_matrix` would enable this by having integral-type vertex descriptors.

Thinking slightly out of the box, have a look at the [Parallel Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph_parallel/doc/html/index.html) (Parallel BGL). It's very likely that it does what you want (and more) but better?

#### Tiny Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0bff23789c38adcb)</kbd>**

Sample output (on my system):

```
Generated 50000000 vertices in 1879ms
Using 8 threads.
Sum of volumes for 50000000 vertices in 94ms: 2.5603e+10
```

Full listing:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/random.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <random>

static std::mt19937 prng { std::random_device{}() };

struct MyVertex {
    uintmax_t volume = [] { static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> pick(0, 1024); return pick(prng); }();
};

using namespace boost;
using G = adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS, MyVertex>;

G generate() {
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    G g;
    generate_random_graph(g, 50000000, 0, prng);

    auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cerr << "Generated " << num_vertices(g) << " vertices " << "in " << duration_cast<milliseconds>(end-start).count() << "ms\n";

    return g;
}

int main() {

    auto const g = generate();

    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    double sum = 0;
#pragma omp parallel
    {
#pragma omp single
        std::cerr << "Using " << omp_get_num_threads() << " threads.\n";

#pragma omp for reduction(+:sum)
        for (G::vertex_descriptor u = 0; u < num_vertices(g); ++u) {
            sum += g[vertex(u, g)].volume;
        }
    }

    auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cerr << "Sum of volumes for " << num_vertices(g)                                << " vertices "
              << "in "                 << duration_cast<milliseconds>(end-start).count() << "ms: " << sum << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Great answer as usual. It's my understanding that parallel bgl is a distributed multi-node set of tools while openMP is for multi-threading on a single node.

Comment: @pbible that is true. However one could perhaps leverage the distributed models and treats each core as a node, so as to benefit from existing distributed algorithms