# Random access (or otherwise fast access) of edges in boost graph library

Tags: c++, boost, graph, random-access, graph-tool

I want to run Monte Carlo edge swaps, i.e., picking two existing edges in a graph uniformly at random and then (if some conditions are met) swap their end points.

I am currently using `boost::random_edge` for selecting edges uniformly at random.

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/erdos_renyi_generator.hpp>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/variate_generator.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/random.hpp>
#include <boost/random/linear_congruential.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS,boost::vecS,boost::undirectedS> Graph;
  typedef boost::erdos_renyi_iterator<boost::minstd_rand, Graph> ERGen;
  typedef boost::uniform_int<> UniformIntDistr;
  typedef boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, UniformIntDistr> IntRNG;

  // make random graph
  int n = 17000;
  boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edges_size_type m = 250000;
  boost::minstd_rand gen;
  Graph g(ERGen(gen, n, m), ERGen(), n);

  // make random number generator
  boost::mt19937 rng;
  UniformIntDistr dis(0, num_edges(g)-1);
  IntRNG gen_int(rng, dis);

  // select two edges uniformly at random (a million times)
  Graph::edge_descriptor e1;
  Graph::edge_descriptor e2;
  for (int i=0; i<1000000;i++) {
    Graph::edge_descriptor e1 = boost::random_edge(g, gen_int);
    Graph::edge_descriptor e2 = boost::random_edge(g, gen_int);
  };
}
```

For graphs with >250k edges, this turns out to be rather slow; each use of `random_edge` takes around 1 to 10 milliseconds. In a previous version that took equally long to run, I used `std::advance` on `edges(g).first` (with `gen_int` as above). In that version, `std::advance` took up the lion share of the computation time.

I assume that things would run much faster if I could get a random access iterator for `edges(g)`, similar to the random access to vertices [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135470/random-access-of-vertices-using-boostgraph).

However, I'd be open to other approaches too. There should be some way to do this, because there is an implementation of Monte Carlo edge swaps in the [random_rewire](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/generation.html#graph_tool.generation.random_rewire) function in graph-tool, which runs much faster than my code.

Comment: I found that, for some combination of the many keyword args for `random_rewire`, the graph-tool command does exactly what I want it to (creating a graph with a given degree-degree assortativity matrix), so I ended up switching back to graph-tool to achieve the best performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't have random access for adjacency-lists:

- [Reason for not allowing random access to the vector of edges in adjacency lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603089/reason-for-not-allowing-random-access-to-the-vector-of-edges-in-adjacency-lists/39611344#39611344)

Here's a benchmark of different approaches to shuffle edges:

- [How to efficiently shuffle edges in a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40610242/how-to-efficiently-shuffle-edges-in-a-graph/40621178#40621178)